# Oracle How to find employees who are getting 60 years old in next 3 months

Tags: oracle

Can anyone please help here. How to find employees who are turning 60 in next 3 months. I have tried multiple options with trunc and round but some border cases are still not able to capture.

e.g. if today is **8th July 2021**
then for first it should print **N** (this is today so ignore this)
2nd,3rd,4th it should print **Y** (as these dates are within next 3 months)
for last 2 records it should print **N** (as these dates are after 3 months)

```
with birthday(
select date '1956-07-08' d from dual unionall
select date '1956-07-09' d from dual unionall
select date '1956-08-08' d from dual unionall
select date '1956-09-08' d from dual unionall
select date '1956-10-08' d from dual unionall
select date '1956-10-09' d from dual unionall
select date '1956-10-10' d from dual unionall )
select d from birthday;
```

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format. And show what you have tried already. Explain why/where it failed. Be specific (error message, unexpected result, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You can use ADD_MONTHS() either in a case expression or in a where clause to calculate the date range birthdates need to fit into  like these examples:

```
with birthday as (
select date '1961-07-08' d from dual union all
select date '1961-07-09' d from dual union all
select date '1961-08-08' d from dual union all
select date '1961-09-08' d from dual union all
select date '1961-10-08' d from dual union all
select date '1961-10-09' d from dual union all
select date '1961-10-10' d from dual)

select 
d,
case when d >= add_months(sysdate,-723)
     and d < add_months(sysdate,-720) then 'Y'
     else 'N'
end as is_60
from birthday
;
```

or

```
select 
d
from birthday
where d >= add_months(sysdate,-723)
and d < add_months(sysdate,-720)
;
```

note 720 months = 60 years and 723 months is 60 years and 3 months, hence birthdays in 1961 are needed in your sample data. OR you did want 1956 dates, you wanted 65 years so change the 720 & 723 to 780 & 783.

Comment: My Bad it was 65 years but when i am running this it is giving me only one record '1961-07-08' it is not giving other records for Aug, Sept and Oct Month

Answer (score 0):

I have used

floor((add_months(**dob**,780)-sysdate)/((add_months(sysdate,3)-sysdate)/3)) which is giving me expected results but was looking any other approach for this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm one day late so today is 9th of July and results are different from what you expected yesterday. That's why I included a `today` CTE, to *simulate* that today is 8th of July 2021:

```
SQL> WITH today AS (SELECT DATE '2021-07-08' to_day FROM DUAL)
  2    SELECT b.id,
  3           b.d,
  4           t.to_day,
  5           ADD_MONTHS (b.d, 12 * 65) will_be_65,
  6           CASE
  7              WHEN ADD_MONTHS (b.d, 12 * 65) BETWEEN t.to_day + 1
  8                                                 AND ADD_MONTHS (t.to_day, 3)
  9              THEN
 10                 'Y'
 11              ELSE
 12                 'N'
 13           END result
 14      FROM birthday b CROSS JOIN today t
 15  ORDER BY b.id;

        ID D          TO_DAY     WILL_BE_65 RESULT
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 1956-07-08 2021-07-08 2021-07-08 N
         2 1956-07-09 2021-07-08 2021-07-09 Y
         3 1956-08-08 2021-07-08 2021-08-08 Y
         4 1956-09-08 2021-07-08 2021-09-08 Y
         5 1956-10-08 2021-07-08 2021-10-08 Y
         6 1956-10-09 2021-07-08 2021-10-09 N
         7 1956-10-10 2021-07-08 2021-10-10 N

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```

---

You'd run just this (using `SYSDATE`):

```
  SELECT b.id,
         b.d,
         CASE
            WHEN ADD_MONTHS (b.d, 12 * 65) BETWEEN TRUNC (SYSDATE) + 1
                                               AND ADD_MONTHS (TRUNC (SYSDATE), 3)
            THEN
               'Y'
            ELSE
               'N'
         END result
    FROM birthday b
ORDER BY b.id;
```